# Monitor is cutting off on both sides in Windows 7 - was working fine with Vista

Tags: windows-7, display

I have dual monitors, and after installing windows 7 64-bit on a new hard drive, my monitor gets cut off on both the sides.

I tried adjusting it on the monitor itself, but did not work, and I also tried adjusting them through the monitor settings in control panel, but it refuses to stretch horizontally.

Comment: Is the proper display adapter driver installed and up-to-date? Is the display resolution set to the monitor's native resolution?

Comment: have to agree with techie007 it is likely that the install used different drivers.

Answer (score 0):

First, check that the driver is up-to-date.

Second, their may be quirks if you just updated. Sometimes changing your resolution and then changing it back can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the refresh rate in your display settings. Usually it should be around 60Hz but some monitors prefer higher rates.